# Hibernate Validator 4 standalone: class constraints caching

Tags: java, validation, hibernate-validator

I want to use Hibernate Validator 4 as a standalone package (i.e. without
Spring/Hibernate). The code which I found was the following (MyBean is some
bean with Hibernate Validator 4 annotations, myBean is its instance), and
it indeed returns the constraint violations:

```
    ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
    Validator validator = factory.getValidator();   
    Set<ConstraintViolation<MyBean>> result = validator.validate(myBean);
```

However, I realized that the Validator instance does not seem to be per class; 
if somebody knows: does Validator cache the constraints it got from processing myBean
(so that when I make the call again for the same class, e.g. validator.validate(myBean2),
it will not again search for annotations etc.)? 
If so, perhaps one also knows where exactly these constraints get cached?

Comment: cannot answer my own question, so here the answer in the form of a comment: yes, ValidatorImpl caches the metadata of the classes in the field beanMetaDataCache.

Answer (score 0):

As you say Hibernate Validator caches the metadata. Here is the class responsible - https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/metadata/BeanMetaDataManager.java

Note, that there is no API to interact with the cache. The cache is cleared after memory demand.

Comment: thank you, my question was about Hibernate Validator 4; it seems to me that at least in the version 4.2 there is no BeanMetaDataManager

Comment: There is, it is called BeanMetaDataCache there. Same thing though. Bottom line, all Hibernate Validator 4 and 5 versions cache the bean metadata one way or the other.

Comment: @Hardy I am looking at 5.2.2 and I cannot find `BeanMetaDataCache` there.